# Stripping superscript from plaintext

Tags: regex, text, replace

I often grab quotes from articles that include citations that include superscripted footnotes, which when copied are a pain in the ass. They show up as actual letters in the text as they are pasted in plaintext and not in html.

Is there a way I could run this through a regex to take out these superscripts?

For example

> In the abeginning bGod ccreated the dheaven and the eearth.

Should become

> In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

I can't think of a way to have regex search for misspellings and a corresponding sequential set of numbers and letters.

Any thoughts? I'm also using Sublime Text 3 for the majority of my writing, but I wouldn't mind outsourcing this to an AppleScript, or text replacement app (aText, textExpander, etc.).

Comment: In the most general case, no: this is very hard and insufficiently well characterize to know how to best attack. In specific cases, it is certainlypossible but probably not worth writing a program for.  The problem is that you don’t know whether the superscripts are before or after the word, whether they have brackets around them, whether they are alphabetic, numeric, or symbolic sequences, &c &c &c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matching Code vs. Matching a Screen**

It's hard to tell without seeing an example, but this should be doable if you copy the text from code view, as opposed to the regular browser view. (`Ctrl or Cmd-J` is your friend). Since writing the rules will take time, this will only be worthwhile for large chunks of text.

In code view, your superscript will be marked up in a way that can be targetted by regex. For instance:

`and therefore bananas make you smartera`

in the browser view (where the `a` at the end is a citation note) may look like this in code view:

`and therefore bananas make you smarter<span class="mycitations">a</span>`

In your editor, using regex, you can process the text to remove all tags, or just certain tags. The rules may not always be easy to write, and of course there are many disclaimers about using regex to parse html.

However, if your source is always the same (Wikipedia for instance), then you can create and save rules that should work across many pages.

Comment: @ThomasScott did this help with your question, or are you still wrestling with it in  your head? :)

Comment: It did answer my question, but is there a way to copy as html without having to open up the developer tools? I was planning on using regex through a shell script wrapped in applescript or auto-hot-key, I guess with your answer in mind, how would I quickly copy source from the browser without opening the inspector? My sources are all formatted the same way, so I'm not seeing that as an issue, the regex will never change... just the copying.... any thoughts?

Comment: @ThomasScott Not sure about that, but I'm not up-to-date on the latest tools... That sub-question would be great for [Stack's SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) as it's not about programming. :)